How to extract text between the LAST TWO instances of a character
I am applying formulas to a large spreadsheet to clean up data.
I have a field (SERIAL #) that has a series of strings separated by semi-colons and I need to extract the text between the LAST two instances of the semi-colon.
Example Data:



ID#
Serial #




77697
VOE1232860; VOE2236458; ERA54265888; LSX558787;


99764
VOE1998572; VOE8547722; ERA55552623; LSX512221;



In the example above, I am trying to Extract LSX558787 from row 1.
Please note I do not have access to the TEXTBEFORE command in Excel
I have searched many solutions already posted here but they don't seem to fit my needs exactly. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!
I have tried multiple solutions from this website and nothing seems to work.
Most of the solutions are using the TEXTBEFORE command which I do not have access to.

Do the rows always have 4 semicolons?

Is the last instance of ";" always the last character?

=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),";",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)))

@Michal very nice, you should post it as an answer (referencing B2 instead A2)

Have you tried something like this: =TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,";",REPT(" ",100)),200)) and this already has been answered multiple times in the forum, please do some research.

If you have Windows Excel, you can use:
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,";","</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s[last()-1]")


Create an XML where each semicolon represents a node boundary"<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,";","</s><s>") & "</s></t>"
The xPath returns the next to last node (the last node will be the one after the last semicolon)"//s[last()-1]"


Also (equivalent of Filterxml solution in Excel 365)
=LET(split,TEXTSPLIT(B2,";"),INDEX(split,COLUMNS(split)-1))

You can also try this if you are on beta channel:
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,".+;(.+);.*$","$1")



Nice. Also: =REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B3,"(\w+);$",2). It could be applied to the entire range of interest too ;). Also if you want to avoid the use of LET() you can apply CHOOSECOLS() and use a negative column index to pick a column from the end of an array: =TRIM(CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(B2,";"),-2)).

Nice. Also TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B3, ";([^;]+);[^;]*$", 2))

Choosecols with negative index is a good tip.  =REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B3,"(\w+);$",2) also, but not clear from question if semicolon is always last character before end of string so =REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"(\w+);*.$",2) might be necessary.

Using a character not present in input to find the next to last ;:

get penultimate instance of ";"
LEN(B2:B3) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B3, ";", "")) - 1
with instance number for SUBSTITUTE  replace next to last ; with |
get text to the right from |

=TRIM(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        RIGHT(
            B2:B3,
            LEN(B2:B3) -
                FIND(
                    "|",
                    SUBSTITUTE(
                        B2:B3,
                        ";",
                        "|",
                        LEN(B2:B3) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B3, ";", "")) - 1
                    )
                )
        ),
        ";",
        ""
    )
)

If LET is available (Excel 2021 and after):
=LET(
    serials, B2:B3,
    semi, ";",
    bar, "|",
    after_penultimate, RIGHT(
        serials,
        LEN(serials) -
            FIND(
                bar,
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    serials,
                    semi,
                    bar,
                    LEN(serials) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(serials, semi, "")) - 1
                )
            )
    ),
    TRIM(LEFT(after_penultimate, FIND(semi, after_penultimate) - 1))
)


